# How to fix the border in the css so it only appears on the current div only?

Tags: css, inline

I have two divs. One is a set of headers that should be displayed as inline but should be spread. The other one, main-content div,  has a set of divs for each header below. I put a border around the main-content div, but the browser renders this border on top of both divs. How to fix the border so it only appears on the main-content div only and why is this happenning?
[image]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/yuAjBcL1PzN0RBut7pl9)

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
#main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
#headers {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#main-content {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.header{
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 14%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="headers">
        <div class="header">
            Header1
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header2
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header3
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header4
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header5
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header6
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            Header7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        main content
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

1. It works when I put `display:inline-block;`, but is it the correct way of doing it?
2. How do I put a border around `#headers`?

Comment: [See This](http://plnkr.co/edit/rIESt0?p=preview) You can give `float:right;` to the main-content div and using `display:inline-block` is good to go. :)

Comment: @DKM inline-block is good. How about a border around #headers?

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:inline-block` fixed the problems.

```
#headers
  width:100%
  border:1px solid blue
  display:inline-block

.header
  text-align:center
  float:left
  display:inline-block
  width:14%
```

Comment: In this scenario, you can also use `display: block` on `#headers` because the inline-block child elements will be fully enclosed in their parent block (in contrast to using `float: left`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `overflow:auto` (or `overflow: hidden`) on `#headers` as follows:

```
#headers {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

The `overflow: auto` property causes the `#headers` to establish a block formatting context, which means that all the floats will be enclosed within the parent block and will not be affected by any content that comes before or after the parent block.

Your border property will then work as expected.